# playing sound from buffer using pygame

Tags: python, audio, pygame, buffer, playback

I'm trying to play a sound from a buffer in pygame. The following code correctly plays the sound once, but then results in `TypeError: must be string without null bytes, not str`.

```
f = open('sound.wav', 'rb')
data = f.read()
buffer = data[44:len(data)] # start after header
pygame.mixer.Sound(buffer).play()
```

Because the error occurs after the sound has correctly played once, my suspicion is that `play()` expects `buffer` to be longer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using `python` built in function `buffer` as a variable.
Here is python documentation on [buffer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#buffer).

I was able to replicate your error `TypeError: must be string without null bytes, not str`

The modified code that does not give error when buffer is used for assignment as opposed to a variable.

```
import pygame
pygame.mixer.init()

f = open('sound.wav', 'rb')
data = f.read()
#buffer = data[44:len(data)] # start after header
myBuffer = buffer(data , 44,len(data)) 
pygame.mixer.Sound(myBuffer).play()
```

Comment: Wow, I feel like an idiot now. Thank's so much for catching that.